# config365 Outlook error, Outlook cannot log on

Tags: configuration, outlook, microsoft-office-365, exchange-migration, outlook-anywhere

[image]

I have tried to test out outlook once I have run Config365. I have done a cutover migration and everyone has synced. I would just like to test my Outlook just to make sure that all I need to run is Config365 and then I will magically be able to use Office 365 with Exchange online.

Is there anything else I need to do ? as I could do without losing mailboxes for 100 staff.

Answer (score 0):

You have one step missing after you're done with the cutover migration.

You need to start pointing your clients to the cloud mailbox instead of the local Exchange.

Here's a good summary for that: [Local DNS after Office 365 migration](https://serverfault.com/questions/709599/local-dns-after-office-365-migration/712846)

So configure those and if you were unable to connect for any reason to the mailbox online, roll-back your steps and you will get connectivity local Exchange again.